# Can I get a texture onto my second cube?

Tags: javascript, webgl, texture-mapping

I'd like to get an opinion: I currently have the following program consisting of two multi-colored cubes that can be selected via the one html button and rotated by pressing corresponding keys on the keyboard.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;
uniform vec4 posiz;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remember: these matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
                    0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
                    0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
                    0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                    s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
                    s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    // position matrix
    mat4 posMat = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                        posiz[0], posiz[1], posiz[2],  1.0 );

    // size matrix
    mat4 sizMat = mat4( posiz[3],  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  posiz[3],  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  0.0,  posiz[3],  0.0,
                        0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = sizMat * posMat * rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cubev-1.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>

<br/>

<input type = "button" value = "First" id = "switchButton" ></input>

</body>
</html>
```

files webgl-utils.js, initShaders.js, and MV.js can be found here:

http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/

And here is the accompanying javascript file:

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis1 = 0;
var axis2 = 0;

var rot1 = 1.0; // rate of rotation
var rot2 = 1.0;

var theta1 = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
var theta2 = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

// cube position along x, y, and z axis and size
var posiz1 = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ];
var posiz2 = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ];

// used to send info back to html, I think
var thetaLoc;
var posLoc;

var firstCube = true;

    var vertices = [
        vec3( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
        vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
    ];

// indices of the 12 triangles that comprise the cube
var indices = [
    1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 6, 2,
    3, 0, 4, 4, 7, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 6,
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 5
];

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    // array element buffer    
    var iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // color array attribute buffer
    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    // vertex array attribute buffer
    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    // connect location to variable in html
    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta"); 
    posizLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "posiz");

    //event listeners for buttons
    document.getElementById( "switchButton" ).onclick = function ()
    {
        firstCube = !firstCube; // switch between cubes

        if (firstCube) document.getElementById("switchButton").value = "First";
        else document.getElementById("switchButton").value = "Second";
    };

    window.onkeydown = function(event)
    {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

        if (firstCube)
        {
            if (key == 'R') posiz1[0] += .1;
            else if (key == 'L') posiz1[0] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'U') posiz1[1] += .1;
            else if (key == 'D') posiz1[1] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'I') posiz1[2] += .1;
            else if (key == 'O') posiz1[2] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'G') posiz1[3] += .1;
            else if (key == 'S') posiz1[3] -= .1;

            if (event.shiftKey == 0)
            {
                if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z') rot1 = -1.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z') rot1 = 1.0;
            }

            if (key == 'X') axis1 = xAxis;
            if (key == 'Y') axis1 = yAxis;
            if (key == 'Z') axis1 = zAxis;
        }
        else
        {
            if (key == 'R') posiz2[0] += .1;
            else if (key == 'L') posiz2[0] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'U') posiz2[1] += .1;
            else if (key == 'D') posiz2[1] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'I') posiz2[2] += .1;
            else if (key == 'O') posiz2[2] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'G') posiz2[3] += .1;
            else if (key == 'S') posiz2[3] -= .1;

            if (event.shiftKey == 0)
            {   
                if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z') rot2 = -1.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z') rot2 = 1.0;
            }

            if (key == 'X') axis2 = xAxis;
            if (key == 'Y') axis2 = yAxis;
            if (key == 'Z') axis2 = zAxis;
        }
    };

    render();
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // handle rendering of first cube
    theta1[axis1] += rot1;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta1);
    gl.uniform4fv(posizLoc, posiz1);

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    // handle rendering of second cube
    theta2[axis2] += rot2;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta2);
    gl.uniform4fv(posizLoc, posiz2);

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

I have little experience with WebGL and I am trying to get a texture mapped onto the second cube without interfering with the colors on the first. I am trying to go about this by following these instructions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Using_textures_in_WebGL#The_fragment_shader

which instruct me to update the fragment shader in my html to a value I feel would interfere with normal rendering of the first cube.

Am I perhaps going about it the wrong way? Is it realistically possible to map a texture onto the second cube without interfering with the colors of the first? I'd like an opinion because I don't want to chase what could be a dead end.

By the way, if you would like to run the program yourself, here are the controls:

u - up, d - down, l - left, r - right, i - in, o - out, g - grow, s - shrink

x/y/z - spin along cube's x/y/z-axis

shift + x/y/z - same as above but in opposite direction

and the button switches between the cubes.

Thank you so much for your help and time in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing this was too broad a question?

Comment: Note that you can have a shader per cube and use gl.useProgram to switch between shaders at runtime, this will stop 1 cube affecting the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might really find [these tutorials](http://webglfundamentals.org) helpful. In particular [this one about matrix math](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html).

In particular it's not common to do so much matrix creation a vertex shader. Generally all your code about rx, ry, rz, posMat & sizeMat would typically be done in JavaScript and only the result send to the shader. That makes the shader far more flexible because you can do any matrix math you want in JavaScript, not just the 5 hardcoded things you did in your shader. Of course there's also nothing technically wrong with the way you did it. Whatever works for you. I'm just pointing out it's not a common approach.

As for the texture vs your current shader's vertex colors it's common to have hundreds or even thousands of shaders for a large program each with different features. In fact for a 3D engine or game engine it's super common to generate your shaders depending what features you need for that particular object.

At the same time for your particular case, instead of 2 shaders another way to do it might be to mix the color and then set one to white

```
varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColorl = texture2D(texture, texcoord) * fColor; 
}
```

So when you want to draw with a texture

```
// set attributes for texcoord
gl.bindBuffer(..... texcoordBuffer);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, ....);

// set the texture
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
gl.bindTexture(...., texture);

// tell the shader which unit you put the texture on
gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, unit);

// turn OFF the attribute for vertex colors
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(fColorLocation);

// set the attribute so it returns white
gl.vertexAttrib4f(fColorLocation, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

When you want to draw with vertex colors you can do the opposite

```
// set attributes for vertex colors
gl.bindBuffer(..... fColorBuffer);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(fColorLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(fColorLocation, ....);

// turn OFF the attribute for texcoords
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

// bind a white texture
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
gl.bindTexture(...., white1x1PixelTexture);

// tell the shader which unit you put the texture on
gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, unit);
```

At init time you'd create a 1x1 white pixel texture

```
var white1x1PixelTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, white1x1PixelTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0,
     gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([255,255,255,255]));
```

With this style it also means you can use a texture and vertex colors at the same time which is a common way to add variety to something like a terrain map. Just setup both a texture and the vertex colors and they'll be multiplied.

Comment: Thanks. This was an assignment for a computer graphics class. I adapted the code I posted from a previous work so I have a very rudimentary understanding of what exactly is going on. Truth is, I'm starting to suspect the professor has assigned a lab beyond the scope of most of his students. I'm not even sure the professor's able to do it. Regardless, thank you so much for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

You're asking a fairly high-level question, so here's a high-level answer:

It's certainly possible to have one textured object and one untextured object. There are two basic ways to do it:

1. **Use two separate fragment shaders,** one which does a texture lookup and one with the vertex colors you're already using. You'd do `initShaders` twice, and get two program objects. Then just use `gl.useProgram` to switch between them.

   Note that the values of `uniform`s are specific to a program — so if you want to use the same value for both you have to call `gl.uniform...` once for each program.
2. **Use a condition in the fragment shader** and control it with a uniform variable:

   ```
   varying vec4 fColor;
   varying vec2 texcoord;
   uniform sampler2D texture;
   uniform bool useTexture;
   void main(void) {
     gl_FragColor = useTexture ? texture2D(texture, texcoord) : fColor;
   }
   ```

   Then instead of switching programs like in the first option, you would give `useTexture` a value of 0 or 1 depending on whether you want the texture.

Of these two options, the first one can have better performance because it does not require you to add unused attributes to your arrays (no color when texturing, no texture coordinates when coloring) and does not require the GPU to evaluate the condition.

The second one, using a condition, has the advantage of simplicity. Additionally, if you have several different rendering options, it doesn't require you to compile shaders for all possible combinations of options (which can be very slow).

In the long run, I recommend having both techniques in your toolbox and using whichever one best suits the problem. In this particular case, you're working with so few vertices and so simple shaders that it doesn't really matter which one you use.